# Selling subcription using google play billing without backend

Tags: android, google-play-billing

I'm trying integrating google play billing into my app to sell subscription.
I wonder if I can do it without providing backend in 2024

is it possible until now?
I previously read a question about this but it's too outdate

I expect I can sell subscription without providing backend